# A question of topological sum of subspaces

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question... I believe it is true but I don't know how to prove it...

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A_1,A_2$ disjoint subspaces of $X$.

If we consider the topology of subspace on $A_1\cup A_2$, is it true that $A_1\cup A_2 = A_1\oplus A_2$?

Thanks.

Comment: If $A_1\oplus A_2$ has the topology where a set $U$ is open if and only if $U\cap A_1$ and $U\cap A_2$ are open, then $A_1=[-1,0)$, $A_2=[0,1]$ is a counterexample in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ohhh, I'm so disappointed :( ... thanks, Stefan!

Comment: The intuition from this counterexample should tell you that being disjoint as sets does not mean "topologically disjoint". The issue comes about because, despite the fact that $A_1, A_2$ in Stefan's counterexample are disjoint as sets, there is a point in one that is close to points in the other. We need to separate the sets topologically. Given the right notion of what that means, then what you stated is true.

Comment: @StefanH. Could you copy that into an answer below so this question does not show up on the unanswered queue? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This can fail terribly. E.g. in $\mathbb{R}$ take the disjoint subsets $A_1 = \mathbb{Q}$ and $A_2 = \mathbb{P} = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then in $A_1 \cup A_2$ no non-empty subset of $A_1$ nor one of $A_2$ is open, while in the topology on $A_1 \oplus A_2$ all such sets would be open in the total space.

Stefan's example from the comments (also in $\mathbb{R}$): $A_1 = [-1,0), A_2 = [0,1]$ also works: e.g. their union is compact, their topological sum is not (only if both would be compact).

It *is* true if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint closed, or disjoint open subspaces of a space $X$. For the former case, a set $A \subset A_1 \cup A_2$ is closed iff there is some closed subset $A'$ of $X$ such that $A' \cap (A_1 \cup A_2) = A$, and then $A$ can be written as $(A' \cap A_1) \cup (A' \cap A_2)$, which is a union of two closed sets of $X$ which are also closed in $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively. So there the description of closed subsets of the union and the topological sum *do* coincide, and the same argument also holds for disjoint open sets.

I suppose the same would more generally hold for separated subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$ of a space $X$ (so when $\overline{A_1} \cap A_2 = \emptyset = A_1 \cap \overline{A_2}$), as then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are relatively clopen sets in the union, and we could have the same arguments.